# Redefine labels to animation slider in plot_ly

Tags: r, dataframe, animation, plotly

I'm trying to set the labels for the animation slider using `plot_ly()` in R. Here's a minimal example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

dat <- tibble(x = rep(seq(1,5), 2), f = rep(c(1, 2), each = 5))
dat <- dat %>% mutate(y = x^f)


steps <- list(
  list(label = "a", method = "restyle"),
  list(label = "b", method = "restyle")
)

plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x = dat$x,
            y = dat$y,
            name = "Tæthed",
            frame = dat$f,
            type = "scatter",
            mode = "lines") %>%
  animation_opts(frame = 0) %>%
  animation_slider(steps = steps)
```

From what I could gather, the `steps` option in `animation_slider()` needs a list of lists, one for each value of the slider. I am misspecifying it somehow because the labels aren't "a" and "b" but 1 and 2. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do works with `sliders` (part of `layout`): https://plotly.com/r/sliders/

But there is no `step` argument for animations: https://plotly.com/r/animations/

We can modify the dataframe beforehand to show the right frame name:

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(fr = letters[f]) %>% 
plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x = ~x,
            y = ~y,
            name = "Tæthed",
            frame = ~fr,
            type = "scatter",
            mode = "lines") %>%
  animation_opts(frame = 0) %>%
  animation_slider()
```

[image]

Comment: Ah yes, of course. That was simple. Thanks! Do you know if there is a way to determine ticks and labels of the slider bar? Say I have a lot of frames and only want labels for a handful of them.

Comment: @StefanHansen I don't think there's a straightforward way to do this. Although, I have been distant from plotly for a while, so it's possible I am missing something.

Comment: In fact plotly's `animation_slider` also uses steps - but currently the R library [doesn't allow to customize them](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/1719).

Comment: Ah, that's a shame. Being able to customize the steps argument of `animation_slider` would indeed be a nice feature. I guess it could be done manually via the `layout` function? Like the Sine Wave Slider example of https://plotly.com/r/sliders/ @ismirsehregal?

Comment: @StefanHansen exactly. [Here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/blob/cdfdc7c1b7eb8b787f90ddf166ac9ad59d5cee98/R/animate.R#L216) you can find the current implementation.